# Reverse Usage of admin inline: Error message no foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

Error Messages

```
<class 'app.inlines.ContactInline'>: (admin.E202) 'delegator.Contact' has no ForeignKey to 'delegator.Organisation'.
```

I intend to use the model Contact in Organisation and also in User(Member) and ended up with the error messages above.

models.py:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
    contact_detail = models.OneToOneField(Contact, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Organisation(TenantMixin):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=24, unique=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='LN')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    contact_detail = models.OneToOneField(Contact, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Organisation)
class OrganisationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['key', 'type', 'name', 'domain_url', 'schema_name']
    actions = ("export_as_csv",)

    inlines = [ContactInline]


@admin.register(Member)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'group', 'role')

    inlines = [ContactInline]
```

inlines.py

```
class ContactInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Contact
    extra = 0
    max_num = 1

    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['address']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['zipcode', 'place']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['country']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['phone_landline', 'phone_mobile', ]}),
        (None, {'fields': ['website']}),
    ]
```

This is not excactly what I expected. Is there onother possibility to rech this without creating two extra models for organisation contacts and user contacts and linking them with a foreign key relation?

Comment: What is `ContractInline`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, edited.

Comment: Or should one make contact an abstract class and the two additional classes OrganisationContact and UserContact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an app where you can come around this limitationa and you can create The Model as above but instead use the [django-reverse-admin](https://github.com/daniyalzade/django_reverse_admin) within your admin class.

Then the fields are rendered as expected and not only shown as **str**